# CURL passes the valus = null

Tags: php, curl

Hi below is a piece of code that I use to pass my variables to another server using cURL. Although there is contact with the other server the passed variables display 
username=null etc. If would really appreciate your suggestions. Thanks in advance

1. ```
   if(!isset($_COOKIE['admin'])){

       include_once("login.php");

       echo ("<div id='quote'>Error: Can not access page.");   }

   else {       if (isset($_GET['user']) && ($_GET['user'] != "") &&
   isset($_GET['pass']) && ($_GET['pass']  != "") && isset($_GET['to'])
   && ($_GET['to'] != "") && ($_GET['username'] != "")) {

                       $username = $_GET["username"]; 

           $idlicenza= $_GET["user"];

           $licence = $_GET["pass"];

                       $to = $_GET["to"];
                       $acc = new Account;

                       $acc->changeVis($idlicenza, $licence, $to);             header("Location: search.php?user=".$username); 




                   $ch = curl_init();

               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://xxxx/add-user");

               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                                         "username=userId&idliscence=codes&myid=password");

                   // receive server response ...

               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

               $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

               print_r($server_output);

               curl_close ($ch);
                       }    } ?>
   ```

Comment: html encode your vars before posting them if your username is for example "usern&me" or "user'name" or "user"name" etc etc etc it'll break the curl post.  You may also want to consider building an array or an object first then json_encode or serialise it then base64encode it then send it so rather than sending lots of fields you're sending just one.  on the receiving end you base64 decode it then jsondecode or unserialise it to get your usable array / object back.  This also saves the need for doing the html entities and special chars conversions.

Comment: Also you're not actually posting your local vars across eg: username=userId isn't putting in your variable from php it should be username=$userId